# How to print the text values of an XML doc with XMLEventReader when some elements don't have text

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I have an XML doc that I am parsing which has elements like this...

```
 <item>
  <g:product_type>Accessories</g:product_type>
  <g:item_group_id>85953</g:item_group_id>
  <g:tax>
    <g:country>US</g:country>
    <g:rate>0.00</g:rate>
  </g:tax>
</item>
```

Notice how some elements like product_type and item_group have text values, but the tax element has sub elements(no text value of its own).

I am parsing this with XMLEventReader, and if an element has text then I want to print it....

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
InputStream in = read();
XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);

while (reader.hasNext()){
        XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent()
        if (event.isStartElement() ){
             System.out.println("The value is" + reader.elementText);
         }
   }
```

But right now because I have that one element which doesn't have text, it gives an error like this..

```
elementGetText() function expects text only elment but START_ELEMENT was encountered.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:851)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.getElementText(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:188)
```

How can I modify the code above so XMLEventReader ignores such elements which don't have text? I didn't see anything in the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) to check if an element is text.

Comment: is sax a requirement or you would be interested in some simpler solutions than using stax?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#peek()) to check what the next event is going to be. You can then use method [`isCharacters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html#isCharacters()) on the resulting `XMLEvent` to find out if the next event is text. Use the method [`asCharacters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html#asCharacters()) on it to get a `Characters` object. Note that you'll want to test for [`isIgnorableWhiteSpace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/Characters.html) so that the empty space between an opening tag and another opening tag without significant text isn't reported.

You'll also want to set property `javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing` to Boolean.TRUE in your `XMLInputFactory` before creating the event reader. That way text won't get broken up into separate events but reported as one chunk between tags. Otherwise, larger pieces of text or nodes with newlines in them might generate multiple events.

Maybe you want to end up doing something more complex with those text nodes, but if not, you could also get the same result quite simply using an XSLT transformation.